# I'm new to pthreads and using them alongside a mutex. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to use them?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

EDIT(because people are asking some questions that i expected to be asked because no assignment specifics were given).

I HAVE to use pthreads and the bridge mutex for this assignment, none of the input would cause any huge problems(like a car and boat arriving at the exact same time), my professor made sure none of that would happen with his input. Also, when I mention "sleep" for a duration I mean that specific thread waits for a specified time(that being the time its gonna take for that car or ship to go next). The whole point is to make a new thread each time a ship or car arrives and destruct it once they have crossed and left. I would like to know how to think about this problem and translate that thinking into the correct code.

I have a programming assignment that uses `pthreads` and `mutex`. The point of the program is to take in an input (a `.txt` file), said input will look like this:

```
Bridge digit1 digit2
CarOrBoat CoB_name dig1 dig2
CarOrBoat CoB_name dig1 dig2
...
```

Basically the list has in the first line(always) the word "bridge" followed by 2 numbers, the first being the time it takes for the bridge to go up and the second for  the time it takes to go down. For any of the other lines, where it says "CarOrBoat", will be either "car" or "boat" (declaring what is crossing the bridge), followed by the name of said CoB(Car or Boat), and then finally the next 2 numbers are the time elapsed since the previous arrival of a CoB and the time it takes to cross the said bridge, respectively. I have the data input down, for now, I am reading each line and putting it into a struct node, their data being string type(CoB), string name, int dig1, int dig2. I then for now put the nodes into a list for testing purposes. I'd like to later just call a thread as soon as I read the data but I can get to that later. Anyways, my read input is put into a vector which contains every instruction(I ignore the very first line and only use its dig1 and dig2).

The goal of this whole assignment is to(by using `pthreads` and 1 mutex[the bridge]) let cars and boats cross the bridge only 1 at a time and by taking turns(for example if in line there are 5 cars and 5 boats, we[depending on bridge status, but if we are at the state of a ship having gone through first, we lower the bridge for the car] lower the bridge[which takes dig1 time, and for any time that we are waiting for an action to happen, we sleep for that time, we only sleep for bridge going up and down and car or ship crossing time], then let the car pass through. After a car passes, IF there is a boat in the queue, raise the bridge and let the boat go through, vice versa for if a boat went through and IF a car is in the queue. If there are > 1 cars and no boats then let the cars go through without raising the bridge, and vice versa for if there are > 1 ships.

How would I go about this using `pthreads` and a `mutex`(the bridge)? If needed I can provide the assignment exact details

I haven't tried anything as I don't know how to use `pthreads` and `mutex`, I've tried reading up on them and I understand whats happening in the examples and text I am going over but I cannot take that and apply it to my assignment. Here is my code (in c++, this is all in c++):

````
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;
/*Functions----------------*/




/*                          */
static pthread_mutex_t theLock;
static pthread_cond_t carCanGo;
static pthread_cond_t
int nCars = 0;
int nShips = 0;
int bridge_up;
int bridge_down;
bool draw_bridge_status = false;
//False means it is up, unavailable to cross the channel as a ship

struct node {
    string carORboat;
    int first_time;
    int second_time;
    string thing_name;


    node(string type, int ft,int st, string name){
        this->carORboat = type;
        this->first_time = ft;
        this->second_time = st;
        this->thing_name = name;
    }
    node(){
        ;
    }
};
//Functions for the car crossing the bridge
void CarPassing(string nameOfCar, int time_to_cross){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&theLock);




    pthread_mutex_unlock(&theLock);
}

void ShipPassing(string nameOfShip, int time_to_cross){
    pthread_mutex_lock;
}

int main(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&theLock, NULL);
    vector<node*> theList;
    string fileName;
    cin >> fileName;
    string firstLine;
    string currLine;
    

    fstream theFile;
    fileName.erase(remove(fileName.begin(), fileName.end(), '\n'), fileName.end());
    fileName.erase(remove(fileName.begin(), fileName.end(), '\0'), fileName.end());
    fileName.erase(remove(fileName.begin(), fileName.end(), ' '), fileName.end());
    theFile.open("input1.txt");
    if(!theFile.is_open()){
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    }
    getline(theFile, firstLine);
    string garbo = firstLine.substr(0,firstLine.find(' '));
    firstLine = firstLine.substr(firstLine.find(' ') + 1);
    bridge_up = stoi(firstLine.substr(0, firstLine.find(' ')));
    firstLine = firstLine.substr(firstLine.find(' ') + 1);
    string bridge_going_down = firstLine.substr(0);
    bridge_down = stoi(bridge_going_down);
    while(getline(theFile, currLine)){
        currLine.erase(remove(currLine.begin(), currLine.end(), '\n'), currLine.end());
        currLine.erase(remove(currLine.begin(), currLine.end(), '\0'), currLine.end());
        string cob = currLine.substr(0, currLine.find(' '));
        if(cob == "Car"){
            nCars++;
        }
        else{
            nShips++;
        }
        currLine = currLine.substr(currLine.find(' ') + 1);
        string cob_name = currLine.substr(0, currLine.find(' '));
        currLine  = currLine.substr(currLine.find(' ') + 1);
        int ft = stoi(currLine.substr(0, currLine.find(' ')));
        int st = stoi(currLine);
        node* temp_node = new node(cob, ft, st, cob_name);
        theList.push_back(temp_node);
    }

    /*------------EVERYTHING HAS BEEN READ IN FROM THE FILE UP TO THIS POINT*/








    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Why use the platform specific C library `pthread` in C++ where you have a standard `std::thread` that works cross platforms (since C++11)?

Comment: Probably for the same reason as `vector<node*> theList;`: Teaching from an obsolete lesson plan. That Man, do yourself a favour and allow `theList` to store the `node`s directly, `vector<node> theList;` and later `theList.emplace_back(cob, ft, st, cob_name);`. It'll save you some pain managing all of those allocations manually and the program will probably be a little faster.

Comment: Warning: `getline(theFile, firstLine);` needs a test for success or `string garbo = firstLine.substr(0,firstLine.find(' '));` and friends could be processing garbage.

Comment: Recommendation: Build up to this task. Play around with threads and mutexes in a few smaller, lower-stakes programs to gain familiarity, then dive into this task.

Comment: Ditto what Ted Lyngmo said. If the teacher _requires_ you to use pthreads in a C++ program, then I guess you do what you've got to do, but it's a _Seriously Bad Idea._ Don't ever use pthreads in a C++ program when you're the one who's making the decisions.

Comment: P.S., If I were assigned to simulate a drawbridge crossing, full stop, then I would not use threads. Again, If the teacher _requires_ you to use threads, then you do what you've got to do, but you should maybe ask the teacher _why_ are you using threads? and, how many threads? and, what is each thread supposed to do?

Comment: Re, "... we sleep for that time..." FYI: If we were seriously simulating this thing (e.g., to provide evidence to the DOT in support of some big new highway project) we would not `sleep`. We would update a _variable_ that represents how much simulated-world time has passed. We should be able to simulate a whole year's-worth of car and boat traffic in a matter of seconds (maybe mere milliseconds) of real-world time.

Comment: Re @TedLyngmo Like I said I am new to using pthreads and have just been using the quickest google search for parts of my code that pertain to using threads. If you could explain further why using the std::thread would be better and also explain on how to use it that would be very helpful.

Comment: Re @SolomonSlow I can definitely ask him this question but he did say before that the point of this assignment is to get used to using pthreads, he said this assignment shouldn't be too hard code wise, just that the logic will be hard to understand. He did also say that the code should be no more than 200 lines, supporting the "shouldn't be to hard to code" part.

Comment: @That_Man_EA `std::thread` is in the C++ standard. `pthread` is not.  `std::thread` has a C++ API where you can for example start a thread in a member function. `pthread` can not. The C++ thread primitives are RAII wrappers around whatever thread library the platform use so your don't get resource leaks. You also have small RAII wrappers to get automatic unlocking of mutexes etc. `pthread` has nothing of that. Too bad you _HAVE_ to use `pthread`. It's just wrong. The only time I care about the platform's thread library is when I need to do something with that API, which is extremely rare